# Sudden increase in app blocks and prevention of app sharings by facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

we couldn't post anything at our game application (App id: 205934316099103 , Display name: Cafeland, Link: http://apps.facebook.com/cafeland). After we inspected, we get this error "top.location.href="/help/contact.php?show_form=post_problem";" from graph api. We looked at insights and we have seen the app blocks rate goes up too high suddenly in 1 April and then our all sharings blocked between 8-9 April. We haven't done any  change that can perform mailicious action or increase sharings so we didn't understand the problem. Any idea?

Comment: No, we have no idea.  Check your limits, and see if you're exceeding them.  Failing that, asking Facebook directly is probably the best approach, since it's their API.